# Performance of WatchConnectivity WCSession.sendMessage

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos-2

Has Apple indicated what are realistic expectations for the transmission time from watch to iPhone for `sendMessage(_ message: [String : AnyObject]...)`? For a message that is a single String I'm seeing an average of 180 ms (200 attempts), which seems way to long. It seems long relative to ping times on a wifi network, which are 4 ms. All watch-to-iPhone transmission times were measured with a vanilla Swift watch app/extension and iPhone app.

I'm using sendMessage in a game, and I'd like this to be as small as possible. I'm having a really hard time determining if sendMessage is a realistic approach if I need transmission times less than 50 ms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can depend on a certain transmission speed. While the method can only be called if the devices are paired, there is no guarantee how good the connection may be. The connection strength could be degraded by the distance between devices, if there is anything between the devices, etc.

The connection between the devices is likely optimized for being more power efficient than for speed.